# Cross browser advanced tooltip capability on <option> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

Today, HTML  tags support "title" attributes on all major browsers.  When you hover over an option in a drop down list, the title will appear as a tooltip.  What event allows the title to display?

I should state that this is my first time asking a question.  In keeping with the guidelines, I have researched this quite thoroughly to the best of my ability but I am not an expert in this area.  This topic has been covered repeatedly but there has never been a definitive answer (at least I can't find one).  I have coded many approaches and all of them work in Firefox but not in any other commonly used browser.  I have seen many dated suggestions but almost nothing after about 2007 and none of them work (not even the ones specific to IE).  Either I am missing something or I still have a lot to learn (both are likely).

Obviously, I am looking for something beyond a simple text tooltip.  What I would like to do is display a small image nearby as the user moves the cursor over the various options in a select list.  Piece of cake in Firefox (I can do it several ways) but no other browser seems to support this.  Apparently, the other browsers do not support mouseover or hover on option tags yet, that title will appear.  There must be an event that triggers it.  Why can't it be used?

Any and all ideas and suggestions gratefully accepted.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this is not implicitly supported by official DOM so you have to create custom dropdown box.

http://www.sitepoint.com/16-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/

you can code it to work however you want but there is no way to do it with html dropdown(select/option) element.